# How to see parameters of a struct in Julia?

Tags: struct, julia

In Python the command `dir` on an object returns the object's properties and methods. Is there an equivalent command in Julia? I know Julia does not have methods in the sense of Python's objects, but can we see the parameters of a struct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are referring to the fields of a struct, then you can get a list of the field names using the `fieldnames(T)` function where `T` is of type `DataType`.

So say you want to know what fields some variable `a` has, you could do `fieldnames(typeof(a))`.

Comment: Also, you can use `fieldtypes` to get field types.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [`fieldnames`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.fieldnames) and [`fieldtypes`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.fieldtypes), from the other answer, the [`dump`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.dump) function can be used for introspection of both types and values, for example

```
julia> struct Foo{S, T<:AbstractVector{S}}
           x::T
           y::Int
       end

julia> dump(Foo)                                 # <-- dump on the type
UnionAll
  var: TypeVar
    name: Symbol S
    lb: Union{}
    ub: Any
  body: UnionAll
    var: TypeVar
      name: Symbol T
      lb: Union{}
      ub: AbstractArray{S, 1} <: Any
    body: Foo{S, T<:AbstractArray{S, 1}} <: Any
      x::T
      y::Int64

julia> dump(Foo([1, 2, 3], 1))                   # <-- dump on a value
Foo{Int64, Vector{Int64}}
  x: Array{Int64}((3,)) [1, 2, 3]
  y: Int64 1
```

Answer (score 1):

@frederikekre's answer reminded me of the amazing package [Eyeball.jl](https://github.com/tshort/Eyeball.jl). It lets you interactively explore types and their instances, get docs for them, methods that operate on them (`methodswith`), etc. (Note however that it's at version 0.4.4, and there's still the occasional bug you might encounter.)

Here, after typing `eye(fb)`, I pressed down arrow once to go to `r: RegexMatch`, and then `m` to get the list of methods that accept a `RegexMatch`.

```
julia> struct FooBar
         r::RegexMatch
         s::SubstitutionString
       end

julia> fb = FooBar(match(r"\d+", "test123"), s"42")
FooBar(RegexMatch("123"), s"42")

julia> eye(fb)
[f] fields [d] docs [e] expand [m/M] methodswith [o] open [r] tree [s] show [t] typeof [z] summarize [q] quit
     : FooBar  FooBar(RegexMatch("123"), s"42")
 >    r: RegexMatch  RegexMatch("123")
       match: SubString{String}  "123"
        string: String  "test123"
        offset: Int64  4
        ncodeunits: Int64  3
       captures: Vector{Union{Nothing, SubString{String}}} (0,) 0 Union{Nothing, SubString{String}}[]
       offset: Int64  5
       offsets: Vector{Int64} (0,) 0 Int64[]
       regex: Regex  r"\d+"
        pattern: String  "\\d+"
        compile_options: UInt32  0x040a0002
        match_options: UInt32  0x40000000
        regex: Ptr{Nothing}  Ptr{Nothing} @0x00000000024163f0
      s: SubstitutionString{String}  s"42"
       string: String  "42

Opening methodswith(`r`) ...

[f] fields [d] docs [e] expand [m/M] methodswith [o] open [r] tree [s] show [t] typeof [z] summarize [q] quit
 >   : Vector{Method} (12,) 96 Method[FooBar(r::RegexMatch, s::SubstitutionString) in Main at REPL[25]:2, eltype(m::RegexMatch) in Bas
      1: Method  FooBar(r::RegexMatch, s::SubstitutionString) in Main at REPL[25]:2
      2: Method  eltype(m::RegexMatch) in Base at regex.jl:262
      3: Method  getindex(m::RegexMatch, idx::Integer) in Base at regex.jl:245
      4: Method  getindex(m::RegexMatch, name::AbstractString) in Base at regex.jl:251
      5: Method  getindex(m::RegexMatch, name::Symbol) in Base at regex.jl:246
      6: Method  haskey(m::RegexMatch, idx::Integer) in Base at regex.jl:253
      7: Method  haskey(m::RegexMatch, name::AbstractString) in Base at regex.jl:258
      8: Method  haskey(m::RegexMatch, name::Symbol) in Base at regex.jl:254
      9: Method  iterate(m::RegexMatch, args...) in Base at regex.jl:260
      10: Method  keys(m::RegexMatch) in Base at regex.jl:219
      11: Method  length(m::RegexMatch) in Base at regex.jl:261
      12: Method  show(io::IO, m::RegexMatch) in Base at regex.jl:227
```